# Text to Divisor Class Encoding in Hyperelliptic Curve Cryptography

Tags: elliptic-curves, elgamal-encryption, encoding

When trying to implement ElGamal Public Key Encryption using Hyperelliptic Curves, one needs to map the message that will be encrypted to a valid Divisor (in my case in the Mumford representation, which is the most common).

I have not found any specific methods similar to Koblitz encodings in ECC. Are there any methods out there that can be presented in a more algorithmic way so that they can be implemented in code?

Comment: There's [Deterministic Encoding and Hashing to Odd Hyperelliptic Curves](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/382.pdf) by Fouque and Tibouchi.

Comment: This works, but only for Odd Hyperelliptic Curves. I want something more generic  like this https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-89339-6_11 however this still limits the type of curves that can be used. I was wondering if a typical Koblitz encoding from byte to point in the HEC and then to Divisor in Mumford representation can be used in this case and if not, why? Any ideas?